# Unreal 4.25 - cannot use "GetAllActorsOfClass" in "Object" class based blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I try to make a blueprint that does not have a 3D representation in the game world

**I used "Object" as the base class**

**but now I cannot find/use GetAllActorsOfClass** in the blueprint editor (even when disabling context sensitivity)

now I may have been to far up the class hierarchy

**I cloned the unreal repository but I can't figure what is the minimum base class to use to have access to GetAllActorsOfClass**

any help appreciated on this

[image: ed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetAllActorsOfClass` node is a call into `UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass`. This function requires a world context. `UObject` does not provide a world context by default - i.e. a call to `UObject::GetWorld` is not guaranteed to be successful.

Use `Actor` as your base class. It will not have a 3d representation if you don't add any renderable components.

Comment: but how do you create such an actor programmatically ? spawn requires a transform so it's definitely located somewhere...

Comment: It's located somewhere if it has a root component, as blueprint based actors will have, but it doesn't need to have a visual representation.

Comment: ok I just feed it the identity matrix, but it feels awkward, I just want a data holder; since GetAllActorFromClass is an utility, it makes no much sens to be implemented that way tbh...it feels like the actor is still part of the scene graph

Comment: @Phil123456 If you think about it, then so are AWorldSettings, AGameMode, AGameState, APlayerState, etc. The other option is inherit from UObject in c++ and implement GetWorld